# Saving all push notifications data got for an app when app is in terminate or inactive state

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to iOS development and currently i'm working on push notifications.I have a requirement where I will get push notifications for different functionalities in an app. When app is in terminate or inactive state all notifications will display in system notifications panel. When I tapped on particular notification remaining notifications data is lost. Is there any thing like we can store all push notifications data and when launching we can execute one by one.

Answer (score 0):

No, not on iOS. 
Apps like facebook do this by keeping the state of the push notification on there server. Thus allowing a client to fetch the alerts and show their read state.

Comment: Hi rckoenes, I have one more doubt. There are some applications like Whats app which is completely depends on push notifications. while app is in terminate state we will get messages. when we click on particular messages app will open and we can able to read all the other messages also. How it is possible. Could you please explain me.

Comment: There is no API for accessing the notifications in the message center. Also Whatsapp is not using push notification to send messages, they use XMPP. They just send out push notification to inform the user that a new message form them has been received. Also they use silent push notification and then fetch the message via XMPP and decrypt the message. This is because WhatsApp has end to end encryption. After the message has been decrypted they use local notification to push a notification on the message center.

Comment: I read about silent notifications. In notification content- available property with a value of 1 then remote notification works  as a silent notification. And then if we write a method - “(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler “ we can bring app from suspend state to background. But what is that UIBackgroundFetchResult. In article related to notifications they  mentioned  UIBackgroundFetchResult will give 30 seconds time.What is that 30 seconds time?

Comment: It's the result handler you call after you are done fetching data. This is what iOS use to check if you successfully retrieved data.

Comment: It means with silent notifications and completion handler API  we can bring app from terminate to  background and we can fetch data from server and we can store the data?

Comment: Yes. Short answer. If the user has turned off push notification and background running then no.

Comment: Is there any thing like we have to fetch data in 30 seconds. Because UIBackgroundFetchResult will give 30 seconds time. That i didn't understand. It won't effect the functionality right?

Comment: The 30 is only for background fetching not perse for handling the silent push notification does not have this limit. But I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Now I got some clarity on how to handle push notifications. I will try this one out. Thanks for your help rckoenes.